# Mudar texto de uma div dentro do fancybox

Tags: javascript, html, fancybox

Tenho um popup usando Fancybox, dentro dele tenho uma div, preciso alterar de forma dinâmica usando Javascript o texto da mesma. Estou usando o código a seguir na chamada do clique de um botão:

```
$('#id-da-div').html('Novo texto');
```

Este código simples funciona em qualquer lugar dentro do meu site, mas quando a div esta dentro da Fancybox não funciona. Ele não da erro algum, simplesmente não atualiza o html dentro da div.

Deve ser algo da Fancybox, preciso resolver por preciso colocar um contador dentro do popup.

Obrigado.

Comment: Tenta selecionar o elemento com o painel do navegador.

Comment: Já fiz, inspecionei o elemento e o html da div se mantem estatico, mesmo sem mostrar erros no console.

Answer (score 0):

Selecionar o elemento dentro da Fancybox:

1. Tecle F12 para abrir "ferramentas do desenvolvedor" no navegador.
2. Selecione o elemento que tem o texto a ser alterado.
3. No código-fonte mostrado no painel, clique com o botão direito do mouse
   sobre o elemento.
4. No menu selecione "Copy > Copy selector" e cole o código copiado no
   seletor do jQuery: `$('CÓDIGO_COPIADO').text('Novo texto');`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: o Copy Selector me retorna #id-da-div que é realmente o id da minha div, que eu defini. Eu já tenho o id dela, mesmo usando ele o texto não é alterado.

Comment: Então eu não entendi. Vc quer alterar uma DIV da Fancybox ou uma que vc mesmo fez?

Comment: Eu fiz, ela esta dentro da fancybox, ela faz parte do conteúdo que carreguei na fancybox. Na verdade, pode ser qualquer elemento dentro da fancy, seja um text ou div, nao consigo alterar nenhuma informação usando javascript dos elementos dentro da fancy.

Comment: Estranho. Será que essa id não está duplicada?

Comment: Não tem como dar errado quando vc seleciona a div pelo copy selector.

Comment: Faz uma busca por essa ID no código-fonte. Não pode haver mais de 1.

Comment: Vou fazer mais uma analise e volto a postar. Obrigado.

Comment: Já revisei tudo, não existem duplicações, no codigo fonte da página a div esta sendo mostrada normalmente. Tenho muita experiencia com desenvolvimento web, mas dessa vez não vejo o que pode estar errado.